# Sending the session id from an Android App to a Jersey web service

Tags: java, session, jetty, jersey-2.0, jsessionid

I got an Android application which is supposed to communicate with a web service which was implemented using `Jersey` and `Jetty`.

I can read the incoming session Id using this code:

```
private static void getCookie(HttpResponse httpResponse)
{
    Header[] headers = httpResponse.getAllHeaders();
    for (int i=0; i < headers.length; i++)
    {
        Header h = headers[i];
        String s1 = h.getName();
        if(s1.equals("Set-Cookie"))
        {
            sessionCookieValue = h.getValue().split(";",2)[0];
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

This seems to work and I get a value like this in the cookie value: `JSESSIONID=8pdfuwgduykls5cvj971ylrc`

The problem is that I don't seem to send it properly. The web service is injected with a `HttpServletRequest` parameter which is supposed to hold the session id but it doesn't.

The way I'm trying to pass it is like this:

```
DefaultHttpClient  client = new DefaultHttpClient();
CookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();
BasicClientCookie cookie = new BasicClientCookie("JSESSIONID", sessionCookieValue);
cookie.setPath("/");
cookie.setDomain(MyApplication.WEB_SERVICE_BASE_ADDRESS); //"192.168.200.158/"
cookieStore.addCookie(cookie);
client.setCookieStore(cookieStore);
HttpResponse httpResponse;
try
{
    httpResponse = client.execute(request);
        ...
}
```

Why isn't the session id injected to the request in the web service?

Comment: Try to set cookie domain. Also, in your code, cookie name is "Cookie". I think it is dummy value right because it should be "JSESSIONID"

Comment: What exactly should the domain be? I'm just connecting to a web service with an ip address I got

Comment: then set cookie domain value to IP address

Comment: just cookie.setDomain(webServiceIpAddress);  ?

Comment: yes, it should be like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finally figured out the problem.

The initial comments were correct - the cookie's key in the `BasicClientCookie` should be "JESSIONID". The path and domain should be set like I did there.

The main issue was simply removing the "JSESSIONID=" prefix from the `sessionCookieValue. After I removed it, everything worked.